# Extensible support for open source section in Careers

Tags: feature-request, jobs

At the time of writing, the Open Source section of Careers supports just four open source providers: github, bitbucket, googlecode, and sourceforge. Why just these particular providers? I have one on SourceForge but another on an unsupported one, CodePlex. It would be beneficial to support more open source providers but, even more importantly, I would really appreciate the ability to manually add an open source project here in the Open Source section. (Yes, I could add it under "projects and links" but it belongs here.)